# How to get value in url from php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to get the value of url from php in wordpress. url: `https://www.domain.com/category/cricket/`

I want to get cricket value from url i tried by

```
<?php $value=$_GET['cat']; ?>
```

Above code worked fine when i set url to defult (`https://www.domain.com/?cat=17`) in wordpress but didn't worked when it is set to "pretty permalinks" (`https://www.domain.com/category/cricket/`).

How can i get the value of url in wordpress from php when it set to "pretty permalinks" (`https://www.domain.com/category/cricket/`)

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to get the category ID, and then [`get_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) to get the category object:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $category = get_category( get_query_var('cat'), false );
    echo $category->slug;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `get_queried_object()` to get the current category:

```
$category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
echo $category->slug;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
<?php
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $cat->cat_ID; //the category id
$cat_name = $cat->name; //the category name
$cat_slug = $cat->slug; //the category slug
?>
```